# Apple MacBook Pro track pad not working

Tags: mac, macbook, touchpad, macbook-pro

I have a very strange problem with my gf MacBook Pro. After last big update on 22.12. my track pad is not working at all.
I wasn't present when the update happened, but I was told that "everything worked fine, but after reboot, trackpad is not working at all".
I tried to reset SMC, reset NVRAM, remove old OS and make a clean install, nothing works permanently. Only thing that works for like 20s from boot is SMC reset. Then the trackpad stops working again.

Data about the machine :

Current OS - High Sierra 10.13.2

Mac BookPro (Retina, 13 inch, mid 2014)

Model ID - MacBookPro11,1

Boot ROM - MBP111.0142.B00

SMC - 2.16f68

I am not Apple expert, so please if I am missing something you need, to troubleshoot, just tell me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Like it or not, it’s probably just bad hardware. Apples are so proprietary in their design and software that there is little room for things like this to happen unless hardware is bad. Could be something was spilled on the system and has leaked through the keyboard down to the motherboard. It could also be the battery has started swelling like on some MacBooks and is damaging the touchpad. Could be a number of things.

Comment: since I use that machine from time to time I am sure nothing was spilled. the machine is used at home for little over than 2 years and I take care of some updates, but my wife is IT positive, she understand some IT stuff and  she updated this one. maybe some firmware was not flashed properly, I honestly don't know. I would like to see a standalone package I could run and reflash things with it, but I cant find it. what would be done at this point by Apple technician? could the battery be wrong after 2,5 year? really?

Comment: Can you try using an another mouse to open up System Information and look at the USB/SPI device trees? [You can reflash the firmware](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202040), but I severely doubt this is the case.

Comment: hi JMY.
system is set to Slovak language, but I will translate if you tell me which node you need in English.

USB 3.0 zbernica:

  Ovládač radiča hosta: AppleUSBXHCILPT
  ID PCI zariadenia: 0x9c31 
  ID revízie PCI: 0x0004 
  ID predajcu PCI: 0x8086 

Apple interná klávesnica/trackpad:

  ID produktu: 0x025a
  ID predajcu: 0x05ac (Apple Inc.)
  Verzia: 2.24
  Rýchlosť: Do 12 Mb/s
  Výrobca: Apple Inc.
  ID umiestnenia: 0x14400000 / 2
  Dostupný el. prúd (mA): 500
  Vyžadovaný el. prúd (mA): 40
  Extra operačný el. prúd (mA): 0
  Vstavané: Áno

Comment: the rest is here :
BRCM20702 Hub:
ID produktu: 0x4500
ID predajcu: 0x0a5c  (Broadcom Corp.)
Verzia: 1.00
Rýchlosť: Do 12 Mb/s
Výrobca: Apple Inc.
ID umiestnenia: 0x14300000 / 3 Dostupný el. prúd (mA): 500
  Vyžadovaný el. prúd (mA): 94
  Extra operačný el. prúd (mA): 0
  Vstavané: Áno
Bluetooth Open Host radič:
  ID produktu: 0x8289
  ID predajcu: 0x05ac (Apple Inc.)
  Verzia: 1.43
  Rýchlosť: Do 12 Mb/s
  Výrobca: Apple Inc.
  ID umiestnenia: 0x14330000 / 4
  Dostupný el. prúd (mA): 500
  Vyžadovaný el. prúd (mA): 0
  Extra operačný el. prúd (mA): 0
  Vstavané: Áno